# How to wire action to a button in ControlsFX?

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

In Swing it was possible to connect action to a button and button was reflecting action's parameters like icon, enableness, text and so on.

Is this also possible with ControlsFX' [`Action`](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/action/Action.html)?

If yes then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an existing button you can use [`ActionUtils.configureButton(action, button)`](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/action/ActionUtils.html#configureButton-org.controlsfx.control.action.Action-javafx.scene.control.ButtonBase-).

To create a button bound to the action, use [`ActionUtils.createButton(action)`](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/action/ActionUtils.html#createButton-org.controlsfx.control.action.Action-)